# How to call a directive in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
.directive('clinicalTrailModal', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          context: '=',
          dui: '='
      },
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/lbdAdsModal.html'
   })
```

I am calling this directive based on true false condition like below,

```
<clinical-trail-modal  value="currentUrl" dui="typeDisease._id" data-ng-if="clinicalTrailModal"></clinical-trail-modal>
```

But it does'nt work.When I remove

```
 restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          context: '=',
          dui: '='
      },
```

this it works.I am new to angularjs.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: did you declare the clinicalTrailModal flag?

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly failing due to you passing context into the scope. Either remove context, pass it in, or make it optional.

```
 restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          context: '=?', //optional
          dui: '='
      }
```